# Owl carousel right side space issue

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I have added owl carousel slider on a web page https://jeffbrownyachts.com/site/test5 (news section). Please click on news from the navigation.
Currently, the news is showing as 2 rows 3 columns in an owl carousel slider. The issue is that the owl carousel shows unexpected space at the right corner of the slide. 
https://prnt.sc/patw11. Could anyone tell me the issue?

```
// owl carousel code
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      dots: false,
      stagePadding: 0,
      loop:true,
      margin:0,
      nav:true,
      center: true,
      responsive:{
          0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
          },
          600:{
            items:2,
            nav:false
          },
          1000:{
            items:3,
            nav:true,
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: [It's the overlap](https://i.imgur.com/4BImUWl.png)...

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman How can I fix it?

Comment: It's a property of Owl Carousel. Can't do much.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I could not find the solution could you please explain.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Thanks for the assistance issue is solved.

Comment: Happy to find that the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

There is a width issue in .owl-stage element. The issue is solved by recalculating the width of .owl-stage element through onInitialized event of owl carousel. I solved the issue using this [Github issue](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1139)

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
      var fixOwl = function(){
        var $stage = $('.owl-stage'),
            stageW = $stage.width(),
            $el = $('.owl-item'),
            elW = 0;
        $el.each(function() {
            elW += $(this).width()+ +($(this).css("margin-right").slice(0, -2))
        });
        if ( elW > stageW ) {
            $stage.width( elW );
        };
      }
         $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
              dots: false,
              stagePadding: 0,
              margin:0,
              onInitialized: fixOwl,
              onRefreshed: fixOwl,
              responsive:{
              0:{
                items:1,
                nav:true
              },
              600:{
                items:2,
                nav:false
              },
              1000:{
                items:3
              }
          }
      });
    });
```